# Adding headers to postForObject() method of RestTemplate in spring

Tags: spring, rest, web-services, restful-authentication

I am calling web service using below method.

```
ResponseBean responseBean = getRestTemplate()
    .postForObject(url, customerBean, ResponseBean.class);
```

Now my requirement got changed. I want to send 2 headers with the request.
How should I do it?

Customer bean is a class where which contain all the data which will be used as request body.

How to add headers in this case?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can use `HttpEntity<T>` for your purpose. For example:

```
CustomerBean customerBean = new CustomerBean();
// ...

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set("headername", "headervalue");      

HttpEntity<CustomerBean> request = new HttpEntity<>(customerBean, headers);

ResponseBean response = restTemplate.postForObject(url, request, ResponseBean.class);
```

Answer (score 11):

Just use the `org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders` to create your headers and add CustomBean. Sth looks like:

```
 CustomerBean customerBean = new CustomerBean();
 HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

// can set the content Type
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

//Can add token for the authorization
headers.add(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Token");

headers.add("headerINfo", "data");

//put your customBean to header
HttpEntity< CustomerBean > entity = new HttpEntity<>(customBean, headers);
//can post and get the ResponseBean 
restTemplate.postForObject(url, entity, ResponseBean.class);
//Or return the ResponseEntity<T>
```

Hope this help.